# Convert math formulas to algorithm

Tags: .net, math

I would like to study how to convert  some math formulas i.e.

http://www.mathportal.org/calculus/integrals/integration-formulas-exercises.php into C#/VB.NET code.

Are there any resources to study about it?

Comment: What are you trying to do? An algebra engine or just type them so you can compute them numerically?

Comment: @user877329 Well I put some examples... I have missing that part of knowledge I need right now. So I would like to study  it in some proper manner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In terms of solving, or typesetting, or.... ?

You might like Lehman's "Math for CS" book just google the title, it's available as a PDF online.

Answer (score 3):

[A highly-rated Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30615/Converting-math-equations-to-C) addresses exactly this question - converting mathematical formulas to C#.

The article describes a formula-to-code converter, representing the formulas in MathML then converting them to C#.

Source code for the converter is available for download and may prove helpful on your quest.

Comment: All of the formulas requiring conversion are integrals. The CodeProject article doesn't handle that.

Comment: Point taken, @RaymondChen.  However, [MathML can represent integrals](http://www.bing.com/search?setmkt=en-US&q=integrals+in+MathML); and C# code can calculate them: the converter should be extensible to cover integrals.  Study and work required, yes, but the OP expects both.

Comment: Numerical integration is another order of magnitude harder than formula conversion. It isn't clear whether the OP is simply after formula conversion or actually wants the formulas evaluated.